# Prove that $\int_{\Omega}fd\mu \int_{\Omega}gd\mu\geq 1.$

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose that $\mu(\Omega)=1$ and suppose $f$ and $g$ are positive measurable functions on $\Omega$ such that $fg\geq 1$. Prove that
> $$\int_{\Omega}fd\mu \int_{\Omega}gd\mu\geq 1.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\phi (x)=\frac 1 x$ is a convex function on $(0,\infty)$. By Jensen's inequality we get $\phi (\int fd\mu)=\frac  1 {\int f d\mu} \leq \int \frac  1 f d\mu \leq \int g d\mu$ since $\frac  1  f \leq g$.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution. Since $f,g$ are positive and applying Cauchy-Schwarz:

$\int \sqrt{fg} d\mu \le \sqrt{\int f d\mu} \sqrt{\int g d\mu}$ [1]

Now we can apply the pointwise condition:

$\int \sqrt{fg} d\mu\ge \int 1 d\mu=\mu(\Omega)=1$ [2]

Combine [1] and [2], take square and you are done.